# How to manually start and stop a thread running blocking code within a Python asyncio event loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, python-asyncio

I have an app that runs in asyncio loop. I wish to start a thread which will execute a piece of blocking code:

```
def run(self)->bool:
        self._running = True
        while self._running:
        
            #MOVE FORWORD / BACKWORDS
            if kb.is_pressed('x'):
                self.move_car("forward")
            elif kb.is_pressed('w'):
                self.move_car("backward")
            
        return True
```

until I decide to stop it and manually set the `self._running = False` by calling:

```
def stop(self):
    self._running = False
```

These are both methods of a class controlling the whole operation of a raspberry pi robot-car I made.

I want this to run on a separate thread so that my main application can still listen to my input and stop the thread while the other thread is running in this while loop you can see above.

How can I achieve that?***Note*** For sending the start and stop signal I use `http` requests but this does not affect the core of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code of your blocking function `run` inside the default executor of the loop. This is documented here [Executing code in thread or process pools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools).

```
async def main():
    # asumming you have a class `Interface`
    # that contains `run` and an async method `listen_for_stop`.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    inter = Interface()  
    run_task = loop.run_in_executor(None, inter.run)
    results = await asyncio.gather(run_task, inter.listen_for_stop())
```

With `asyncio.gather` you await for the execution of the two tasks concurrently.

Also you should check [Running Tasks Concurrently](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently).

Comment: hey! thanks but I wanted to start a parallel process that runs the code return success then go do other things while this runs and when the user decided to terminate the thread then   stop it. If I await it like this the thread will never end and the app will never be free to receive the termination message it runs forever

Comment: There is no reason to run forever. `asyncio.gather` is going to return when both tasks returns his values. The app is able to receive the termination message because I guess you are receiving that message in an async way inside the (hypothetical) `listen_for_stop`, once you receive that message can change the `self._running` flag to `False` and return the `listen_for_stop` method, since is already stopped. I think if this isn't what you need you should consider share a bigger part of your code.